# Azure SQL: External table is different than the column's data type in the underlying standalone or sharded table present on the external source

Tags: sql, azure, elasticsearch, azure-sql-database

When I run this stored procedure that is in an Azure SQL database:

```
select c.ID, c.ContractIDText, c.ContractID, c.TpwrId, c.ContractType as ContractType, c.Status as StatusName, c.Grantee as GranteeName,
           c.Contact as ContactName, c.EffectiveDate, c.OptionToExtend, c.OptionExercised, t.ID as Term,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ContractID ORDER BY t.Sequence) as Sequence,
CASE WHEN t.TimePeriod is null then e.DueDate
     WHEN t.TimePeriodUnits = 'Years' then DATEADD(Year, -t.TimePeriod, e.DueDate)
     WHEN t.TimePeriodUnits = 'Months' then DATEADD(Month, -t.TimePeriod, e.DueDate)
     WHEN t.TimePeriodUnits = 'Days' then DATEADD(Day, -t.TimePeriod, e.DueDate)
     WHEN t.TimePeriodUnits = 'Weeks' then DATEADD(Day, -(t.TimePeriod*7), e.DueDate)
     ELSE e.DueDate end as PerceivedEffectiveDate,
          t.TermType as TermTypeName, t.TimePeriod, t.TimePeriodUnits as TermUnitTypeName, e.DueDate as ExpireDate,
CAST(t.TimePeriod AS NVARCHAR) + ' ' + t.TimePeriodUnits as TimeAndUnits,
DATEDIFF(Day, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, e.DueDate) as DaysAway, assetname, County,[Block], Section, ISNULL(Grantor, 'Texas Pacific Land Trust') Grantor
from [dbo].[Contract] c inner join
     [dbo].[Term] t on t.ContractID = c.ID inner join
     [dbo].[Resolution] e on e.TermID = t.ID and (e.ResolutionDescription is null or e.ResolutionDescription = '' or e.ResolutionDate is null or e.ResolutionType is null) left outer join
     [dbo].[Contracts_Tracts] ct on ct.contractid = c.id left outer join
     [dbo].[Tract] tr on tr.id = ct.tractid left outer join
     [dbo].[Land_Surveys] ls on ls.id = tr.landsurveyid left outer join
     [dbo].[Asset] a on a.id = ls.assetid
     where t.TermType <> 'Perpetual' and 
     (
                  c.ContractType in ('Water: Temporary Produced Water Pipeline Permit', 'Water: Temporary Fresh Water Pipeline Permit', 'Water: Salt Water Disposal Load Station Site', 'Water: Salt Water Disposal Letter Agreement','Water: Salt Water Disposal & Facility', 'Water: Salt Water Disposal Facility', 'Water: Salt Water Disposal', 'Water: Salt Water Disposal & Facility', 'Water: Temporary Pipeline Right-Of-Way and Easement', 'Water: Produced Water Pipeline Easement','Multi-Use Pipeline Easement','Water: Temporary Water Pipeline Permit'))
```

I get:

```
The data type of the column 'TpwrId' in the external table is different than the column's data type in the underlying standalone or sharded table present on the external source.
```

The only thing that has changed, that I can think of is moving this database into an elastic pool. I'm thinking it has something to do with cross-database queries.

ContractIdText (will get the same error if I remove TpwrId) is a computed column that utilizes TpwrId.
ContractIdText/TpwrId is in database A and the stored procedure resides in database B. They are both in the elastic pool. The error message is somewhat odd to me.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The external table feature in SQL Azure lets/requires you to define a local schema for a remote table.  (This differs from linked servers in SQL Server where this was done dynamically, but it also is better because it lets the optimizer have statistics on the external table which can significantly improve plan quality).  The issue is that the binding layer between local and remote is seeing different types.  Unfortunately, the error message is not telling you what types (I will go ask the team to improve that error message).  It's not entirely clear which table is an external table (I will guess Contract).  I suggest you step back and try running just "select * from Contract" and see if that returns without error.  If that simplified query errors too, then you should go look at the remote side and try to run whatever the source query is and create a local table out of it (select * into mylocaltable from ()).  Then you can go look in the sys.columns table on each side (local and remote) to see if the types are indeed the same or different.  If they are different, try adjusting the external table definition to align with the remote side.

(Elastic Pools should not really enter into this problem and is not likely to be the cause).

Hope that helps you make progress.
Conor
Architect, SQL

Comment: Conor, thank you. I wound up figuring out the cause. The ContractIdText computed column was a varchar(11) and the external table was set to varchar(20). Although that's not a mismatch, I dropped the external table and recreated. Problem solved, although that was a bit difficult to track down.